# Which could be a subtype of the other

Tags: oop

```
class B {
    …
    /* search for x in a and return the index of the first occurrence,
     * or -1 if not found */
   int search(int[] a, int x) {
       …
   }
   …
}


class C {
    …
    /* produces the same results but uses binary search for speed;
     * the array a must be sorted */ 
    int search(int[] a, int x) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense for either to inherit from the other. Each's `search()` function will differ in functionality. You could create an interface, to ensure that each of your two classes must implement the `search()` function, and then inherit both classes from the interface. 
So, like this:

```
interface A { int search(int[] a, int x); //no implementation details }

class B { int search(int[] a, int x) { // Here is class A search implementation }

class C { int search(int[] a, int x) { // Here is class B search implementation }
```